# Once an array-of-T has decayed into a pointer-to-T, can it ever be made into an array-of-T again?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So let us say I have an array:

```
int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Now if I were to check the type of 'a', on my machine I get:

```
cout<<typeid(a).name(); // prints 'A3_i'
```

Now if I take the address of 'a', then dereference that address, the type does not change (which I really like, because in my mind 'taking the address' and 'dereferencing' are inverse operations):

```
cout<<typeid(*&a).name(); // also prints 'A3_i'
```

However if I dereference 'a' first, then take the address of that, the type *does* change (which I admit I have a hard time not liking, because when I dereferenced the array I should get an int, and when I take the address of that int, I should get a pointer-to-int, and it turns out I do):

```
cout<<typeid(&*a).name(); // prints 'Pi'
```

So here are my two questions:

1)  Once an array-type has decayed into a pointer-type, is there anyway to get it back to an array-type?

I tried the obvious strategy of casting-like-you-just-don't-care:

```
cout<<typeid( (int[3]) &*a).name(); // does not compile
// "error: ISO C++ forbids casting to an array type `int [3]'"
```

Is there another cast that would work?  Or it is this type of conversion strictly off-limits?

2)  Whether or not you can ever get back to the array-type, exactly what information is sliced and lost in the decay-to-pointer proccess?

I understand that a pointer-type and an array-type are not equivalent.  I assume that the array-type is a strict superset of the information stored in the pointer-type.  Does this sound right?

I have read in other questions that the extra information in the array-type is: knowledge of whether or not the array is on the stack, and also its size (it must know the size of the array somehow, because it is part of the type, right?).  Is there any other information hidden in the array-type?

Comment: I would observe that int[3] is not a type, though int[] is.

Comment: @Daniel: "Array of 3 ints" is definitely distinct from "int[]", and "int[3]" seems like reasonable shorthand for the former.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks- `int[3]` is a type; it is the type of arrays of three `int`s.  When you declare a variable using the syntax `int arr[3]`, you are declaring a variable called `arr` with type `int[3]`.  This is why the names of arrays in the scope where they're declared work differently from pointers to the first element of the array; the type `int[3]` is distinct from `int*`.

Comment: Similar: [Can I reverse the process of array-to-pointer decay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635549/can-i-reverse-the-process-of-array-to-pointer-decay)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you're looking for, but you can use typecasting to get back an object with the same type as the original array.  The idea is to use the little-known types pointer-to-array and reference-to-array to recover the information.  For example:

```
char arr[137];
cout << sizeof(arr) << endl; // Prints 137
cout << sizeof(arr[0]) << endl; // Prints 1
cout << sizeof(&arr[0]) << endl; // Prints 4 (on my system)
cout << sizeof(*&arr[0]) << endl; // Prints 1
cout << sizeof((char (&) [137]) *&arr[0]) << endl; // Prints 137
```

The idea is that we typecast the reference created by using `*&arr[0]` to type `char (&)[137]`, a reference to an array of 137 characters.  Now that the reference has this type, the `sizeof` operator knows that it should print 137, since the size of an array of 137 characters is indeed 137.

However, this only works if you typecast to the correct type!  For example, this is perfectly legal:

```
char arr[137];
cout << sizeof((char (&) [42]) *&arr[0]) << endl; // Prints 42
```

So you can recover the information, but you can easily get that information wrong and lead to a case where you've recovered the incorrect information.

Again, I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but it shows that you can indeed use casting to get back the array size information.

Comment: But aren't you kind of just telling the cast what you want to hear?

Also, I want it to work on the composition of &*a (which causes the type to change from array-type to pointer-type), not the composition *& (which leaves the array-type unchanged).

Comment: @Jimmy- You're absolutely right - this just tells the array what its size is, hence the "I'm not sure what you're looking for."  For the case of `&*a`, you can use the cast `(T (*)[size])&*a` to tell the array its original size, BTW.  I'm pretty sure that in general this can't be done and once the array size is gone, it's gone, but in the case where you have special knowledge of what the size ought to be I think what I have is correct.

Comment: That's neat. When I try: cout<<typeid( (int(*) [3]) &*a ).name()<<endl; // prints PA3_i ... which is a pointer to the type I want ... so then I tried: cout<<typeid( *(int(*) [3]) &*a ).name()<<endl; // prints A3_i ... which is the type I was after. I don't understand the order of the parse (so I don't know if the type was actually lost), but I think that answers my first question in the affirmative (provided you know the size, which is fine). Any thoughts on the second question?  p.s.  I don't know why it shows int() when I actually typed int(*) in this comment...

Comment: @Jimmy- That typecast converts the pointer into a pointer to the original array.  You then need to dereference it to get back to the original array: `cout << typeid( *(int (*) [3]) &*a ).name()<<endl;`

Comment: That makes good sense. I take 'a', I deference it and get an int, then I take its address and get a pointer-to-int, then I cast that to a pointer-to-array-of-ints (where I have to tell it the size), then I dereference that and get my array-of-ints. Brilliant! So, provided I used the 'correct' size then everything seems cool, but have I lost any information contained in the original array-type?

Comment: @Jimmy: I don't believe so (though given that this is C++, I'm willing to concede that I'm quite likely wrong!)  The compiler uses the type of the array for pretty much all the decisions it makes except for code generation (where it lays everything out).  You've just constructed an expression with the same type as the original array, so anywhere you use that expression the compiler will have access to all the information about the type that it would from the raw array itself.

Comment: "So you can recover the information, but you can easily get that information wrong and lead to a case where you've recovered the incorrect information." This isn't information **recovery** at all.

Comment: @Karl Knetchel- You're right; that was a poor choice of words on my part.  A better term would have been "reattachment," since you're taking information (that may or may not be correct) and grafting it back on to the expression.  Thanks for pointing this out... I definitely don't want to confuse people!

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer to your questions, but here's what I have to offer -

I don't think there is a way to get back to an array type once it has decayed to a pointer.

The original array type is ***T[N]***, where *N* is the number of elements in the array. Once it has decayed to a pointer the size information is lost for good. As @templatetypdef's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838535/once-an-array-of-t-has-decayed-into-a-pointer-to-t-can-it-ever-be-made-into-an-a/6838707#6838707) shows, you can cast the pointer back to array type, but then he goes on to prove that by casting you're just telling the compiler what the size is, it doesn't actually have a way of deducing that information from the pointer.

To preserve the original type information you'd have to pass the array by reference instead of by pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<size_t N>
void ByRef( int(&array)[N] )
{
  std::cout << typeid(array).name() << std::endl;
}

void ByPointer( int *array )
{
  std::cout << typeid(array).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid((int(&)[4])array).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid((int(&)[42])array).name() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int a[4] = {1,2,3,4};

  ByRef( a );
  ByPointer( a );

  return 0;
}
```

The output of the above is

```
A4_i
Pi
A4_i
A42_i
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're getting at, but once you take the `&` of anything, all you've got is an address.  And simple non-object data structures contain no descriptors, so there's no way, given the address, to get any more information for whatever it addresses.  Even the fact that it addresses, say, a `char` is only conveyed by the pointer type -- if you cast to `void*` then that information is lost (to the extent that it ever existed).

> I understand that a pointer-type and an array-type are not equivalent. I assume that the array-type is a strict superset of the information stored in the pointer-type. Does this sound right?

Information is not "stored" in a type.  Information (if it exists at runtime) is stored in variables.  In C/C++ there is no dynamic typing for non-objects, so not only is information not "stored" in types, but type information is not "stored" anywhere.  Type information is purely a compile-time concept, and it "flows" from one point to another in a program purely as the result of static analysis by the compiler.  Ie, it's a convenient fiction.

Comment: I believe I understand your explanation.  What I called 'type information' is just a specification that directs the compiler to act properly.  So the 'extra information' in an array-type just amounts to extra checks done during compile-time (i.e. compile-time verifications that a pointer-type is not necessarily subject to)?

Comment: There is no run-time type information unless you enable it for polymorphic classes, or unless you count the stuff used to implement the polymorphism in the first place. However, the compile-time type information controls more than just "extra checks"; arrays aren't pointers. `int x[3]`, conceptually, allocates memory on the stack for a block of 3 integers, whose address can be figured out on demand (the decay process); `int* x`, conceptually allocates memory on the stack for an address, without specifying what it's the address **of**.

Comment: Jimmy, I think you've got it.  On most machines there isn't even a way to tell if a group of bits is a pointer or not, vs an integer, group of characters, or something else.  There are a few machines (IBM iSeries being the only one still made, I believe) that are "capability based" and which have a way to distinguish pointers from other data (and, in addition, which have some runtime clues as to the type of data addressed), but these are the definite exception.