# Can I reverse the process of array-to-pointer decay?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, casting, reference

Is it legal to cast a pointer to the first element of an array to a pointer to the entire array?

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void whatever(T(&)[N])
{
    std::cout << N << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int * p = a;
    whatever(*(int(*)[10])(p));   // <-- legal?
}
```

This prints 10 on my compiler, but I'm not sure if the C++ standard allows it.

Comment: Well, if I were you, I would open the standard and read. FWIW, I think it's legal. But I am Ruby developer, so what do I know? :-)

Comment: I believe it is, since you can take the address of an array in a pointer and use that pointer to access element zero, and then you can either increment that pointer to access every single one of the rest of the elements of the array, or use that pointer as an array itself. (i = p[5]) But I rescinded my answer, and turned into a comment, because a belief of mine does not stand a chance against a guy (@Armen Tsirunyan) with 32.7k reputation citing the standard.

Comment: Just a note: The template is resolved at compile time and the type is that of the cast that you have forced, independent on `p`, that is you would get the same output from `whatever( *(double(*)[10])0 )` and that is completely unrelated to whether the conversion makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not legal(as in it's Undefined Behavior). A pointer to the whole array is `&a` not `p`. Basically, you're casting one pointer to another. The standard describes all the allowed conversions and this one is not among them.

Comment: So we can treat a pointer to the array as a pointer to the first element but we can't we treat a pointer to the first element as a pointer to the array? Or is neither of these an option?

Comment: OK then, what about `int (*b)[10]; copy(&p, &p + sizeof(p), &b);`?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Neither is an option

Comment: @KerrekSB: I am not sure about that

Comment: I don't think it is undefined behavior at all. That cast is a `reinterpret_cast` and as such is *unspecified* (rather than undefined behavior)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: You can't treat a pointer to an array as a pointer to its first element. `int (*)[10]` won't happily convert to `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having concluded that

- converting a pointer to the first element of a POD-struct into a pointer to the POD-struct
- converting a pointer to one element of an array into a pointer to an array of size sufficiently small

are both well defined.  But if the first conclusion was quite direct (i.e. there was a section in the standard saying so in quite plain words), the second took several steps (i.e. you needed to put together several part of the standard and draw a conclusion) and I've no time to redo the search now.  If nobody gives citations one way or the other, I'll try to come back later with some.

Edit: I've not found my reasoning back. Currently all what I've is that under the assumption that `reinterpret_cast` gives the same result as the array decay, the round-trip from "pointer to array" to "pointer to first element" to "pointer to array" is guaranteed (per 5.2.10/7 in C++98) as the alignment requirement for an array can't be less strict than the alignment requirement for the element.

Comment: So you have a proof, but it doesn't fit into this margin? ;-)